# Spring Boot admin not showing any client applications in dashboard

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I have been following [this tutorial](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.5.3/) for Spring boot Admin, but when I run the admin application I can't see any spring boot client application for monitoring. I have checked that both the admin and client apps are running. Admin is running on port 8080 and client application is running on port 9010

This is what I have done in my **Admin** **application**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Added these annotations

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAdminServer
public class SpringBootAdminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAdminApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is what I have added in my **client application**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and added this in my properties file (YAML)

```
 spring: 
   boot:
    admin:
      url:
      - http://localhost:8080
 management:
   security:
    enabled: false
```

This is what my Dashboard looks like, as you can see there are no applications to monitor.

[image: This is what my dashboard looks like]

Comment: Did you check the logs for exceptions?

Comment: Yeah no exceptions, nothing !!

Comment: set the `logging.level.de.codecentric.boot.admin.client=DEBUG` and look for registration attempts

Comment: @Abhi, did you get the reason for the issue? I am facing same issue so by any chance you can tell solution to fix it.

Comment: Nope, mate !! Nothing so far.

Comment: I had the same issue.  It seemed to be because my spring-boot app was an eureka client but I didn't set up my admin dashboard to use eureka.  I think maybe the client side was not registering because it found eureka on the class path?  Once I made the admin server "eureka aware" it worked.